# Ember CLI model testing fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

Hi i'm trying to write first tests in Ember CLI. This is what my test looks like

```
> ...
> 
> moduleForModel('recipe/recipe', 'Recipe Model works', {
>     needs: ['model:recipe/recipe'] });
>        test('Recipe is a valid ember-data Model', function (assert) {
>     var store = this.store();
>     var recipe = this.subject({name: 'A title for a recipe'});
>     
>     assert.ok(recipe instanceof DS.Model); });
```

And the model recipe/recipe model

```
...
var Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    category: DS.belongsTo('recipe/category', {async: true}),
    file: DS.belongsTo('filerepository/file', {async: true})
});

Recipe.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        { id: 1, name: 'New Recipe'},
    ]
});
```

If i run given test, it outputs : **Error: No model was found for 'recipe/category'**

If i comment //category and //file on model. The test passes. Currently using fixture adapter. When I create records or load them inside app's workflow all the relations work fine. (like store.find('recipe/category') etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare more models you depend on in `moduleForModel`:

```
needs: ['model:recipe/recipe', 'model:recipe/category', 'model:filerepository/file']
```